# Importing into mysql with symbols

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have some data (in csv) per country taken from a third-party source, and I am having some issues importing them into mySQL. 
For example, one column in my table is *Country* with value 'Côte d'Ivoire' - the import in mysql appears to divide this one row of data into two with Country value of 'C'. It is unable to import the text value of 'Côte d'Ivoire'.

This is what I used for the import:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE source_DATA_TABLE;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'H://TESTDATA/2015/source_DATA.csv'
INTO TABLE source_proc_pqr
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\@'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I changed the delimited through my regional settings on my PC to @ but the same problem exists.

Anyone have a fix to this problem? I'm using mySQL workbench (xampp/phpmyadmin).

Comment: what's the encoding of the table? try to switch it to utf8 if it's not.

Comment: It is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

I tried something and it works. first of all the file should be in utf8. and then you can load it like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'H://TESTDATA/2015/source_DATA.csv'
INTO TABLE source_proc_pqr
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\@'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```